# How to add Title to the Navigation Bar in a WPF Frame control

Tags: wpf, frame, controltemplate

I want to use a `Frame` control with a navigation bar that has NavigationUIVisibility="Visible".

I would like to be able to customize the Navigation Bar by adding a title, and possibly by changing its background color.

Googling suggests [it's possible to do this by overriding the  ControlTemplate using Blend](http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/frame-navigation-bar-title-87964.shtml).

Can anyone provide a sample Control Template that will achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get access to Expression Blend, and worked out how it's done.

- Edit the template in Expression Blend
- It then spits out 400 or so lines of XAML with the original Control Template
- which can then be customized.

It does seem to me to be the XAML equivalent of the copy/paste code reuse, but I can't find an alternative.